# JS functional object constructor - Neo4j Database has no method 'query'

Tags: javascript, database, neo4j, underscore.js, node-neo4j

I'm using the [node-neo4j](https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j) library along with node.js, underscore and prototype.

I'm trying to have a model which extends a database adapter. Code first.

**BaseModel.js:**

```
var _ = require("underscore"),
    Neo4jAdapter = require('../adapters/neo4j/Adapter');

function BaseModel() {

    _.extend(this, new Neo4jAdapter());
};

module.exports = BaseModel;
```

**Neo4jAdapter.js:**

```
var _ = require("underscore"),
    Neo4j = require('neo4j');

function Neo4jAdapter() {

    this.db = new Neo4j.GraphDatabase('http://localhost:3000');
};

Neo4jAdapter.prototype.insert = function(label, data, callback) {

    console.log('Neo4jAdapter', 'Attempt to insert node');

    if (label == '') throw 'Label is not defined';

    var query = [
        'CREATE (n:LABEL {mdata})',
        'RETURN n'
    ].join('\n').replace('LABEL', label);

    this.db.query(query, data, function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log(results);

        var result = results[0].n._data.data;
        result.id = results[0].n._data.metadata.id;

        callback(result);
    });
};

module.exports = Neo4jAdapter;
```

The weird thing is the error I'm getting. I won't post all the node.js / express code here, but I'm hitting the insert function with an url. The response I get is the following:

> Message: Object #
>
> GraphDatabase has no method 'query'
>
> Error: TypeError: Object #
>
> GraphDatabase has no method 'query'

**My question is:** Why does the database object does not have the function `query()`, even tho the [docs](http://coffeedoc.info/github/thingdom/node-neo4j/master/) are saying it should have one?

**Possible cause:** I bet the adapter's db object is not populated yet when calling the insert method, but how do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably unintentionally installed the newer, alpha version.

See this issue for a similar problem: https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j/issues/150

> Hi @Christopheraburns! Run this for me:
>
> npm ls neo4j
>
> I'm guessing you've installed node-neo4j v2 (we have
> alpha versions in npm currently), which has breaking changes to the
> API. The output of that npm ls will tell you if you have node-neo4j v1
> or v2 installed (e.g. 1.1.1 vs. 2.0.0-alpha3).
>
> You can downgrade to 1.1.1 by doing:
>
> npm uninstall neo4j npm install neo4j@1.1.1 --save
>
> Alternately, if
> you're interested in v2 (still a WIP! but almost finished, and pretty
> stable), here are some temporary links until this gets merged to
> master:
>
> API docs (WIP):
> https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j/blob/v2/API_v2.md
>
> Hope this helps! Feel free to re-open if this doesn't resolve things
> for you.

So, you probably need to uninstall neo4j and reinstall the older version, or take a look at the `cypher` method in v2.

https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j/blob/v2/API_v2.md#cypher

Comment: It was indeed this problem! Thank you very much. Never thought I would stumple across such an issue :P

Comment: You're welcome. :) You learn how to scavenge for issues quickly after a few years, hehe.